# Create an array with variables only if those contain values

Tags: javascript

I have values as per below.
I have 3 variables: A,B,C.
If these 3 have values like below:

```
 this.A= "1";
 this.B= "2";
 this.C= "3";
```

Then the expected array is:

```
let D=[{id:"1"},{id:"2"},{id:"3"}]
```

If the value is like below:

```
 this.A= "1";
 this.B="" or null;
 this.C= "3";
```

Then the expected array is:

```
let D=[{id:"1"},{id:"3"}]
```

Comment: Changed the tags to just `javascript` as this has nothing specifically related to Angular or even Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of:

- [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out empty and null values, and
- [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the desired format.

This becomes:

```
let D = [this.A, this.B, this.C]
  .filter(val => !['', null].includes(val))
  .map(val => ({id: val}));
```

Demo (with empty string in this case):

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.A = "1";
    this.B = "";
    this.C = "3";

    let D = [this.A, this.B, this.C]
      .filter(val => ![undefined, null, ''].includes(val))
      .map(val => ({id: val}));

    console.log(D);
  }
}

new Foo();
```

Comment: i am new to angular .if this.B = "" or null or undefined; how will i check for undefined

Comment: What about `false`? If you also want to omit `false`, you can simply use `.filter(Boolean)` instead. Otherwise just add `undefined` to the list of blacklisted values (`['', null]` right now). (You didn't mentioin `undefined` in your original question.)

Comment: not false..i am getting the value as undefined..if so i have to check for undefined also.

Comment: Check my last edit then. The array is just a blacklist, add/remove whatever you want from it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jetos excellent answer it's also possible to use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
const D = [this.A, this.B, this.C]
  .reduce((acc, curr) => curr === null ? acc : acc.concat([{id: curr}]), [])
```